# Contour around watermark opencv

Tags: python, opencv, contour, watermark

I want to draw a box around the watermark in my image. I have extracted the watermark and have found the contours. However, the contour is not drawn around the watermark. The contour is drawn across my full image. Kindly help me with the correct code.

The output of contour co-ordinates  are:

```
[array([[[  0,   0]],

       [[  0, 634]],

       [[450, 634]],

       [[450,   0]]], dtype=int32)]
```

The output image is:

[image]

My code snippet is as follows:

```
img = cv2.imread('Watermark/w3.png')

gr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bg = gr.copy()

closing = cv2.morphologyEx(bg, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)  #dilation followed by erosion
#plt.imshow(cv2.subtract(img,opening))
plt.imshow(closing)

_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(contours)
print(len(contours))

if len(contours)>0 :
    cnt=contours[len(contours)-1]
    cv2.drawContours(closing, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
    
plt.imshow(closing)
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `findContours` is having difficulty to find your box contour because expects to run over a binary image. From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html):

> For better accuracy, use binary images. So before finding contours, apply threshold or canny edge detection.

> In OpenCV, finding contours is like finding white object from black background. So remember, object to be found should be white and background should be black.

Thus, after `cvtColor` function apply the `threshold` making sure you have a black background.

```
...
img = cv2.imread('sample.png')
gr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, bg = cv2.threshold(gr, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
...
```

If you run the `findContours` over this binary image you will find multiple boxes

[image] [image]

To get a single box around the whole text you can search for the number of `iterations` parameter over the
`morphologyEx` function that creates one single blob.

```
...
kernel = np.ones((3,3))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(bg, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=5)
...
```

So, after creating the blob apply the `findContours` you already have and use the [minAreaRect](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to find the rotated rectangle with the minimum area enclosing the set of points passed.

```
...
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))

for i in range(len(contours)):
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[i])
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(127,60,255),2)

cv2.imwrite("output_box.png", img)
```

[image] [image]