# Corner coordinates of contours to draw a single rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to find the corner coordinates of the contours drawn around the watermark such that I can draw a single rectangle with those 4 co-ordinates. I am unable to achieve that. Please help me with the code.

This is my code:

```
     img = cv2.imread('Watermark/w1.png')
        gr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
        closing = cv2.morphologyEx(gr, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        bg = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(closing,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
    
    _,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bg, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print(len(contours))
    
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[i])
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(127,60,255),2)
```

[image]

Comment: You were told how to do that in the answer to your previous question. How did that solution not work for you?

Comment: No, the above was the result I got

Comment: I don't see where you've varied the number of iterations in `cv2.morphologyEx` as suggested.

Comment: I get a similar result with varying the number of iterations as per the requirement of the desired output image.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking since you already have the coordinates from "box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)" ?

Comment: Is there a way to find 4 coordinates to draw a single box around the watermark ?

Comment: Yes, there is. If you look at the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763147/contour-around-watermark-opencv), you're thresholding *after* the morphological closing instead of *before* as suggested. After `cv2.morphologyEx`, take a look at the resulting image `closing`. Is the watermark all one blob? If not, then you either need more iterations or a larger kernel. Once you've got all of the watermark connected, **then** find the contour and the `minAreaRect`.

Comment: Also, what version of OpenCV are you using? Your code should not even work on the latest version because the return values for `cv2.findContours` were changed.